# How to print a lines till a valid email id comes in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line 
do
    echo "Name: " "$line"
    while []; do
        #statements
    done
done <input.txt
```

Comment: post your `input.txt` and expected result

Comment: What is `a valid email id`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `break` when the input is validated.
Example:

```
while read -rp "Please enter email address " line ; do
   if [[ "$line" =~ ^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$ ]]; then
      echo OK
      break
   else
      echo "Try again"
   fi
done
```

Comment: You can upvote my ansr or accept it as the best answer for you. Now I only have a downvote.